# Python - ConfigParser TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python

Задача такова, если в файле `config.ini` и в глобальная переменной не одинаковы, заменить значение на значение глобальной переменной, если же одинаковы, вывести сообщение.

скрипт python

```
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
version = 10
def test2():
    global version
    config.read('config.ini')
    old_config = config.getint('INFO', 'version')
    if old_config != version:
        config.set('INFO', 'version', '%d') % version
    else:
        print 'not delete'
    return 'done'
```

config.ini

```
[INFO]
version = 11
```

при таком коде получаю ошибку

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы или опечатались, или не понимаете как работает `%`. Это оператор форматирования **строки**. Вы же пытаетесь применить его к результату функции. Должно быть так:

```
config.set('INFO', 'version', '%d' % version)
```

PS в следующий раз выкладывайте полное сообщение об ошибке, а то не очень хочется копировать это куда, то, запускать, и так далее.

Comment: Не заметил, спасибо )